# Cannot access the login site in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am fairly new to Drupal.

There is a site:

```
www.mysite.com/?q=user
```

I can log in here without problems, however when I try it with the same project in the local machine:

```
   127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject/?q=user
```

It does not work, I get the apache 404 error. `127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject/` does show up, though. `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show us the whole error string? so we can recommend you the proper changes

Comment: @usmanjutt84 it's just the typical Not Found

The requested URL /drupal/myproject/user was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Comment: Did you try to restart apache2 service?

Comment: @usmanjutt84 Yes

Comment: You can copy and paste `.htaccess` file into your project from fresh [drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.59). It works for me on local.

Comment: If you're running a local webserver, you should make sure that it points to the correct directory. E.g. if the virtual host file specifies that your site lives in `drupal`, you might need to access it at a URL like `127.0.0.1/myproject/?q=user`. A good test for this is to try to access a plain text file like `http://127.0.0.1/drupal/myproject/robots.txt`.